# Passing NSobject to javascript using Javascriptcore framework from Swift iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, swift

I am developing a custom cordova plugin. I need to call javascript method from `iOS(Swift)` with `NSObject` as a parameter.

```
let methodToBeCalled = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("videoStreamAvailableForRendering")
    let valueReturnedFromMethod: JSValue = methodToBeCalled.callWithArguments([stream])
    println("valueReturnedFromMethod \(valueReturnedFromMethod.toObject())")
```

"`stream`" is the object I need to pass. While passing string no errors, but when I am passing stream object I get the following error:

> NSForwarding: warning: object 0x100f6f5e0 of class 'SwiftObject' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
>   Unrecognized selector +[SwiftObject copyWithZone:]

Help me out...

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is because `stream` needs to be a subclass of NSObject or it needs to be an instance of class that automatically bridge to Objective C objects.

Check out this article for more details. `String` works because `String` is automatically bridged to `NSString`.

> When you bridge from a Swift array to an NSArray object, the elements in the Swift array must be AnyObject compatible. For example, a Swift array of type [Int] contains Int structure elements. The Int type is not an instance of a class, but because the Int type bridges to the NSNumber class, the Int type is AnyObject compatible. Therefore, you can bridge a Swift array of type [Int] to an NSArray object. If an element in a Swift array is not AnyObject compatible, a runtime error occurs when you bridge to an NSArray object.